# What is the angle and the length of the sum of two complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z = a+bi$, $w = c+di$ and $s = z+w$.

It is very easy and straightforward to calculate $s$, $\arg(s)$ and $|s|$, but what I want to know, is how $\arg(s)$ and $|s|$ are related to $z$ and $w$.

**What is $\arg(s)$ in terms of $\arg(z)$ and $\arg(w)$?
And likewise, what is $|s|$ in terms of $|z|$ and $|w|$?**

Funny enough, complex addition seems to be more difficult than multiplication, when we think about $\arg(z)$ and $|z|$. Even complex multiplication is easier, a simple formula for that using only $|x|$, $Arg(x)$ and other basic operations, can be written like this:
$$zw = |z||w|e^{(Arg(z)+Arg(w))i}$$
And for complex exponentiation it's a bit more complicated and complex (literally):
$$z^w = \frac{|z|^{Re(w)}}{e^{Arg(z)Im(w)}}e^{(Arg(z)Re(w)+ln(|z|)Im(w))i}$$

Comment: Not much can be said about that, at best all you can say is that $|s| \leq |z| + |w|$

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2412297/argument-of-sum-of-two-complex-numbers

Comment: You can't say much about $\arg(s)$ in terms of $\arg(z)$ and $\arg(w)$, and you can't say much about $|s|$ in terms of $|z|$ and $|w|$. However, in terms of $\arg(z)$ and $\arg(w)$ and $|z|$ and $|w|$, you can say everything you want to, using basic trigonometry.

Comment: Yes that post is similar, but im not just asking about that, im asking how to express arg(s) and |s| in terms of |z|, arg(z), |w| and arg(w). Calculating arg(z+w) is just atan((Im(z)+Im(w))/(Re(z)+Re(w)) + or minus pi depending on wether Re(z+w) and Im(z+w) is positive or not. @NaweedSeldon

Comment: Maybe expressing arg(s) is easier by using a combination of arg(z) and |z|? When we think about it, we both know the angles of z and w, and we also know their lenghts, doesnt that form a triangle? [link](https://imgur.com/a/cdfdNdQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no shortcut. Convert to Cartesian, add and back to polar.

This yields

$$|z+w|=\sqrt{(|z|\cos(\text{Arg }z)+|w|\cos(\text{Arg }w))^2+(|z|\sin(\text{Arg }z)+|w|\sin(\text{Arg }w))^2}=\sqrt{|z|^2+2|z||w|\cos(\text{Arg }z-\text{Arg }w)+|w|^2}$$

and similar for the argument.

Comment: If you compare the formula for multiplication and exponentiation to this, addition actually seems more complicated. Who would have thought that in some way, $2+3$ is actually harder than $2*3$ and $2^3$.

Comment: @NilsPhillipTalgö: have a look at $(2+3i)^{1-2i}$...

Comment: Actually, the polar form is very close to the logarithm. $\log z=\log|z|+i\text{Arg }z$. This explains why the product in polar form is easy, $\log zw=\log z+\log w$. And also why addition doesn't work: $\log(z+w)=???$.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an approximation. May be useful:

Regarding angle of sum of 2 complex numbers:
Let $z = |z| e^{j\theta_z}$,$w = |w| e^{j\theta_w}$

$$\angle{z + w} = \theta_z + \angle \left(1+\frac{|w|}{|z|} \times e^j{(\theta_w - \theta_z)}\right) = \theta_z + tan^{-1}(x)$$
$$x = \frac{sin(\theta_w - \theta_z)}{cos(\theta_w - \theta_z) + \frac{|z|}{|w|}}$$

Using [Series of tan inverse x for x > 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504126/series-of-tan-inverse-x-for-x-1) and first term in taylor series for $tan^{-1}(x)$, we get,
$$tan^{-1}(x) \approx 2 \times \frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

$$\angle{z + w}  = \theta_z  + 2 \times \frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}} $$

So deviation of angle of sum from $\theta_z$ is $2 \times \frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}$