# Series of tan inverse x for x > 1

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion, trigonometric-series

The Maclaurin series of the Tan inverse of $x$ works well for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ but it breaks down afterwards because the curve takes a different.
What function defines the curve after $x = 1$? Thanks
Does the Taylor expansion govern the curves' transition?

Comment: Of course it "breaks down" outside of its interval of convergence.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Remember that Arctan(5) for example is pi/2-Arctan(1/5), so, if you just need it to compute values, you can use that identity.

Comment: Beside @BarryCarter's comment, if you want very accurate approximations, they do exist. If this is your problem, just precise it in the question.

Comment: @BarryCarter OscarLanzi Already understood every letter of my question and gave me an impeccable answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you want a series that applies for all real $x$, consider $x=\tan\theta$ and apply the half-angle formula

$\tan(\theta/2)=\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+1}=\dfrac{\tan\theta}{1+\sec\theta}.$

For $|\theta|<\pi/2$ we then have $\sec\theta=\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}$ and this leads to

$\theta=\tan^{-1}x=2\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x}{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right).$

Thus, given a preliminary calculation of $x/(1+\sqrt{1+x^2})$, we can use the Taylor series with that argument. Since $|x|<|1+\sqrt{1+x^2}|$ for all real $x$, the series will converge accordingly.

Comment: You are a God!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! YOU SAVED MY CODE. ''IT WORKS LIKE MAGIC'' THANKS

Comment: I just have the body of a god -- Buddha.

Comment: Thanks!!! hahahaa